# Token authentication on Socket.io with Passport

Tags: node.js, authentication, socket.io, passport.js

I've built a Node.js API that use Passport for authentication.

Once a user is authenticated he can access to the web services with the BearerStrategy.

Now, I'd like to create a chat and allow access to authenticated users only. I found only one solution dealing with token : [jsonwebtoken](https://auth0.com/blog/2014/01/15/auth-with-socket-io/) and I'd like to know if there is a way to use Passport to do that. Specially because I already implemented the Passport Bearer strategy.

Thanks